# Problem of changing Android encryption algorithm to update app on Google Play - from AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding to AES/GCM/NoPadding

Tags: android, android-security

I want to update the app in a long time.
However, Google Play rejected the app for the following reasons.
(Remediation for Unsafe Encryption Mode Usage - support.google.com/faqs/answer/10046138)

The rejected code is as follows.

```java
    public SecretKeySpec generateKey(int keySize) {
       Date date = new Date();
       Random rand = new Random(date.getTime());
       byte[] aesKeyData = new byte[keySize];
       rand.nextBytes(aesKeyData);
       SecretKeySpec aesKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyData, "AES" );
       return aesKeySpec;
    }
    
    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, SecretKey key)
       throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
       InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
       Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); //here
       cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
       byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(data);
       return outputBytes;
    }
    
    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data, SecretKey key)
       throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
       InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
       Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); //here
       cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
       byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(data);
       return outputBytes;
    }
```

This is the problem part. (I guess...)

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")
```

If I change this part to the following, I expect the problem to be solved.

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
```

However, existing app users have encrypted data using `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`.
So, after decrypting with `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` in the newly distributed app, 
user data need to encrypt it with a new algorithm.
In this case, my new app should contain the existing algorithm that is rejected in Google Play.
Then, I guess, Google Play will do the same reject.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: our app was rejected for the reason: Google says that we should use “AES/GCM/NoPadding” instead "AES/ECB/NoPadding" encryption, but we already have many devices using "AES/ECB/NoPadding". Any workaround solution ?

Comment: @matdev not solved. just we asked users to re-enter information. (the worst method...)

Comment: @SKKim were you able to figure out any solution for the above-stated problem. We are also running into the same problem scenario where the existing users are encrypted using AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding and changing the existing encryption algo to AES/GCM/NoPadding will cause compatibility issues.